# Git fails when not run as root

Tags: centos, git

I just upgraded to Git 2.18 via EPEL on CentOS 7 and now Git fails on any operations that involve communicating with a remote server with the message

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://my.repo.git/': Peer's certificate has an invalid signature.
```

This happens with `git clone`, `git pull`, etc. If I run the same commands using `sudo` they work fine. This makes me think that maybe bad file permissions are preventing Git from accessing certificates or credentials that it needs. However, I have no idea where and which certs to check. Running Git in verbose mode emits no additional information.

Comment: IIRC they are in `/etc/pki/ca-trust/`. There may be a bit of magic (the actual ones are links, or exist only after being extracted from something else).

Answer (score 0):

The main issue was that I have two copies of `pkcs11.txt`: a local one in `~/.pki/nssdb/` and a system one in `/etc/pki/nssdb/`. Git prefers the system version over the local user version. For a long time I only had the local version, which has the PKCS info needed to access my repository. At some point, a new package (maybe a Git update) created the system version of the file, which did not have the necessary PKCS info. Hence, Git (via NSS) failed when it started pulling authentication from the system version of `pkcs11.txt`.

The fix was to merge my local copy into the system-wide copy.

Some things that helped figure this out were setting the following environment variables:

```
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
GIT_TRACE_VERBOSE=2
```

and these threads:

https://superuser.com/questions/1091521/centos-7-wont-accept-any-ssl-certificates

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064601/curl-not-working-error-77-for-ssl-connections-on-centos-for-non-root-users